# Counting words in each row and assigning count to predefined columns

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a df which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['id','review','word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6'])

df.append({'id':1.'review':[word1 word2],[word1 word3 word 9]})
df.append({'id':2.'review':[word1 word2],[word1 word6 word 4]})
```

I want to see review for every customer and assign the count for the words which are present as columns values. There might be extra words which are not present in the columns.

For example:

```
id, review,                             word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6

1,  [word1 word2],[word1 word3 word9]         2.     1.    1


2   [word1 word2],  [word1 word6 word4]       2       1           1              1


3.  [word1 word5],[word1 word3 word5]
```

Comment: The `df.append` lines aren't valid Python syntax.

Comment: I have not used that for appending the data in the code. But, that isn't the issue

Comment: And what *is* the issue?

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question

Comment: No, you have only said what you want to do, but not what the problem was when you tried to do it.

Comment: I did not try anything, as i could not think of a solution for this.

Comment: Did you at least try to do *some small part* of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Sklearn's `CountVectorizer`. This will take a column of text and give you a sparse matrix of word counts; you could then convert this into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["review"])

# Convert the sparse matrix to a dataframe (one column per word, one row per review)

count_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names(),
                        data=sparse_matrix.toarray())
```

The end result is a count, for each unique word, of how many times it appears in each review.

Comment: Did not work, I have already got the most frequent words. Want to find the count for them